# How to use ssr supported packages in vue with vue-server-renderer?

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

I tried to use `vue2-google-maps` and it worked well.
Suddenly my computer had stopped working and then I restarted my computer.
Then, strangely, 500-error comes out.

I reverted all codes associated with vue2-google-maps then my project works well.

Even though when I import vue2-google-maps then It occurs 500-error. :(

**App.js**

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';
```

It was working well but now cause of the unknown reason it has been broken...

Here is my console shows error.

```
webpack built 5410edae88d11b814c0b in 2690ms
error during render : /search
/media/bossminion/Work/WeMeet/frontend/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components/infoWindow.vue:3
<template>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/bossminion/Work/WeMeet/frontend/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/main.js:42:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at r (/media/bossminion/Work/WeMeet/frontend/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:9295:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:/external "vue2-google-maps":1:0)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap a442baf8af813fadc2a4:25:0)
error during render : /favicon.ico
/media/bossminion/Work/WeMeet/frontend/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components/infoWindow.vue:3
<template>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/bossminion/Work/WeMeet/frontend/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/main.js:42:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at r (/media/bossminion/Work/WeMeet/frontend/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:9295:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:/external "vue2-google-maps":1:0)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap a442baf8af813fadc2a4:25:0)
```

Is it possible that project that worked well could cause 500-error for no reason?

Environment: Ubuntu 18.04, npm v6.9.0, node v12.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to handle ssr.

**App.js**

```
if (process.browser) {
  const VueGoogleMaps = require('vue2-google-maps');
  Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
      key: 'myKey',
      libraries: 'places',
    },
  });
}
```

Instead of using import, I used require when it is client rendering.

I will be happy if it helped you. :D